# Leaflet in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, leaflet, mapbox

We have an small application(web) in which we used the MapBox with leaflet in that while we dragging and zooming the map with markers its freezes for some seconds in IE whereas its working smooth in other browsers(Chrome, FF & Opera).

Please help us on this,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please detail your IE version and whatever information about the markers (how many, type: default, custom image, divIcon, etc.). Ideally reproduce your issue on Plunker / JSBin / JSFiddle.

Comment: It's also important to detail the version of Leaflet used. Leaflet 1.0.0-rc3 includes some heavy refactoring of mouse events, which were a major source of delays in some scenarios involving IE11.